# ¿como puedo cargar los datos después de la vista u optimizar la carga de la tabla con laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-blade

Tengo el problema que cuando  envió un dato  a desde un formulario lo valido  que no este vació, tomo el  valor del input, y ejecuto un  sp, el problema es que el store me devuelve  mas de 40, 000 datos y hace que demore demasiado en  cargar la pagina, les comparto el código.

El store procedure se tarda 1.0 segundos en  traer el resultado

```
 public function welcome(Request $request){
    //validacion de daotos enviados desde login
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'username'=>'required'
    ]);
    //recojemos el  id que envian desde el  loguin
    $id = $request ->input('username');

    $ids=$id;

    $period='201909';

    $data=DB::select('EXEC Sp_TreePerId ?,?', array($ids, $period));


    return view('welcome', ['data' => $data] );

    //compact('data')
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Creo que tu problema es que el store no deberia devolver 40000 registros. quien los va a leer?

Comment: Lo  leeré, estoy de acuerdo con  tigo, pero  es una solicitud  que me realizaron  que es pintar todos esos datos.

Comment: y va a tardar, siempre... tenes que mandar toda esa info por la red... no se como podrias acelerar ese envio...

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ el problema no es sql.. su query tarda un segundo.. el problema es la cantidad de datos que devuelve

Comment: exactamente ese es el problema, el problema es que me exigen  que estén todos, y no puedo usar un paginado  que refresque la pagina ya que esta se encuentra en un modal. o sea que por pagina cargue los datos de 30 en  30

Comment: No se quien te exige pintar 40k registros en pantalla, seguramente hasta el navegador colapse, dile a quien sea que eso no es recomendable. No obstante una opción podría ser cargar los datos con ajax en bloques de X registros, paginado en el back pero no en el front.